# How to add extra WHERE clauses when retrieving relationships in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities Post and Comment.
Structure:
**Post:**
id
title
body

**Comment:**
id
post_id
body
active

```
class Post
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
 */
private $body;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="Comment",
 *     mappedBy="post"
 * )
 */
private $comments;

class Comment
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="body", type="text")
 */
private $body;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Post",
 *      inversedBy="comments"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *      name="post_id",
 *      referencedColumnName="id"
 * )
 */
private $post;
```

As a result when I want to get all comments for a post I use $post->getComments() and it works.
How I can add extra Where clauses into this relationship if I want to get only posts with active = 1.
I know that I can do it by DQL or queryBuilder but I want to know how I can do it by  mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to retrieve only active comments is to use Doctrine's `Criteria` object in the `getComments` method of your `Post` entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
```

and

```
public function getComments()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', 1));        
    return $this->comments->matching($criteria);
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to prevent multiple queries each time you retrieve the active comments, you'll need to store them in a local variable. Instead of modifying `getComments`, you could add  `$active_comments` and `getActiveComments`, which will populate `$active_comments` and only query the db if `$active_comments` is `false`.

```
class Post {

    private $active_comments;

    public function getActiveComments()
    {
        if(!$this->active_comments) {        
            $criteria = Criteria::create();
            $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', 1));        
            $this->active_comments = $this->comments->matching($criteria);
        }

        return $this->active_comments;
    }
```

Comment: You are right. Thank You. But now each times when I call $post->getComments() doctrine makes one sql query instead of only one sql query (first calling of $post->getComments()). Should I handle it by my self ?

Comment: @aerweb I think you'll need to handle it manually, see update

Comment: Great ! Thank you. I found useful article about it  http://www.boxuk.com/blog/filtering-associations-with-doctrine-2/